# is there any way to create a common method to Email (Like:- Contact us in app)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

i am getting an error:-  `//  Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type 'MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate?'   //`

and if i am not assigning the delegate then i cant able to come back after click on CANCEL in message VC.

See this code:-
now i am doing something like this:-

```
extension UIViewController { 

func contactUs() {

    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self

                    if let name = CurrentUser.name, let phoneNo = CurrentUser.phone {
                        mc.setMessageBody("\n\n\nThanks & Regards\n\(name)\n\(phoneNo)", isHTML: false)
                    }
                 mc.setSubject(emailTitle)
                 mc.setToRecipients(toRecipents)
                 self.present(mc, animated: true, completion: nil)      
       }
    }
}


extension ViewController:  MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func mailComposeController(_ controller:MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result:MFMailComposeResult, error:Error?) {
    switch result {
    case .cancelled:
        print_debug("Mail cancelled")
    case .saved:
        print_debug("Mail saved")
    case .sent:
        print_debug("Mail sent")
    case .failed:
        print_debug("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Mail not sent")")
    default:
        break
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Vipul you are getting error because in your code you are assigning viewcontroller to self so what you need to do is typecast that controller

```
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self as? MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

this will fix your problem and I will also suggest you to give a default implementation to MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate like this

```
import MessageUI

extension MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    public func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?){

        switch result {
        case .cancelled:
            print_debug("Mail cancelled")
        case .saved:
            print_debug("Mail saved")
        case .sent:
            print_debug("Mail sent")
        case .failed:
            print_debug("Mail sent failure: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Mail not sent")")
        default:
            break
        }
        controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

and you don't need to set mc.mailComposeDelegate

Comment: Hi Vipul if you give default implementation then you don't need to set delegate sorry I forgot to mention.